# dictionary of key and list - remove key if any value in list is none

Tags: python

i have dictionary in following format,

```
mydict = 

{ a: [1, 2],
  b: [2, 2],
  c: [1, 0],
  d: [1, 1]
}
```

if any value is `None`

```
{ a: [1, None],
  b: [2, 2],
  c: [1, 0],
  d: [1, 1]
}
```

I want to remove that `key:value` pair.

the output should be

```
    {
      b: [2, 2],
      c: [1, 0],
      d: [1, 1]
    }
```

i am printing it like this,

```
for key, values in mydict.items():
    print key, values
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to remove `None` without starting a new loop within my `for` loop so i tried this,

I tried this,

```
for key, values in mydict.items() if values.items is not None:
```

but it keep giving me invalid syntax error,

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can't write a for statement like that. See [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: My answer below includes the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
for key, values in mydict.items():  
    print key, values
```

into

```
for key, values in mydict.items():  
    if not None in values:  
        print key, values
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = { 'a': [1, None],
      'b': [2, 2],
      'c': [1, 0],
      'd': [1, 1] }

print({k:v for k, v in d.items() if None not in v})
# {'b': [2, 2], 'c': [1, 0], 'd': [1, 1]}
```

If you need a loop like yours:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    if None not in value:
        print(key, value)
        # do your calculations here
```

Comment: You beat me in 1 second

Comment: i want to do it inside my own `for` loop, this doesn't help me.

Comment: your answer will only print the values of k and v, i want to perform other calculations as well in my for loop

Comment: Other calculations on what? You have a dictionary as you wanted. Anyways I've updated mine. Is that helping you?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
mydict = { 'a': [1, None],
      'b': [2, 2],
      'c': [1, 0],
      'd': [1, 1]
    }

from copy import copy

newdict = copy(mydict)

for key, values in mydict.items():
    if None in values:
      newdict.pop(key)

print newdict
```

Comment: is it possibe to do it without copying a dictionary, since its very huge

Comment: Simply use `mydict` instead of `newdict` (works in Python 2.7 but shows error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` in Python 3.x). I used copy to prevent this, as we would changing dictionary contents while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `filter`+`lambda`:

```
d=dict(filter(lambda x: None not in x[1], list(d.items())))
print(d)
```

Or with a for loop:

```
newd = {}
for k,v in d.items():
   if not None in v:
      newd.update({k:v})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dictionary comprehension`

```
your_dict = {key:value for key,value in my_dict.items() if None not in value}
```

Output:

```
{'b': [2, 2], 'c': [1, 0], 'd': [1, 1]}
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as @Austin's answer

Comment: Ops! When I start writing my answer then there is no answer in this question.That's why I haven't noticed his answer.

Comment: this doesn't help me. I want to perform other calculations as well within my `for` loop which i cannot do with this appraoch

Comment: Such as?You can also perform calculations in this way.